# Example of Sharpsign Equal-Sign reader macro?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've seen this used once, but couldn't understand what it does. The reference says that it is

> `#n=object` reads as whatever object has object as its printed representation. 
>   However, that object is labeled by n, a required
>   unsigned decimal integer, for possible reference by the syntax #n#.
>   The scope of the label is the expression being read by the outermost
>   call to read; within this expression, the same label may not appear
>   twice.

Which to me reads as just 56 randomly selected words of English language... Can you, please, show an example of when this may be used?

Comment: `#1=(programmable . #1#)` on #lisp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Common Lisp it is used by the reader and the printer.**

This way you can label an object in some s-expression and refer to it in a different place in the s-expression.

The label is `#someinteger=` followed by an s-expression. The integer must be unique. You can't use the label twice within a single s-expression.

The reference to a label is `#someinteger#`. The integer identifies the s-expression to reference. The label must be introduced, before it can be referenced. The reference can be used multiple times within an s-expression.

This is for example used in reading and printing circular lists or data structures with shared data objects.

**Here a simple example**:

```
? '(#1=(1 . 2) (#1#))
```

reads as

```
((1 . 2) ((1 . 2)))
```

Note also this:

```
? (eq (first *) (first (second *)))
T
```

It is one identical cons cell.

**Let's try a circular list**.

Make sure that the printer deals with circular lists and does not print them forever...

```
? (setf *print-circle* t)
T
```

Now we are constructing a list:

```
? (setf l1 (list 1 2 3))
(1 2 3)
```

We are setting the last cdr to the first cons:

```
? (setf (cdr (last l1)) l1)
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
```

As you can see above, the printed list gets a label and the last cdr is a reference to that label.

We can also enter a circular list directly by using the same notation. The reader understands it:

```
? '#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
```

Since we have told the printer to deal with such constructs, we can try the expression from the first example:

```
? '(#1=(1 . 2) (#1#))
(#1=(1 . 2) (#1#))
```

Now the printer detects that there are two references to the same cons object.

Comment: `read` is a recursive operation. In the case of lists, `(` is a macro character that reads recursively until `)`. What the last sentence means is that you can't use the same label within a `read`, i.e. `'(#1=1 #1=2 #1#)` is invalid, the label `1` is used twice in the same outermost call to read. When loading or compiling file, every top-level form will be read in a separate outermost `read` call, so there's no problem in using the same label in different top-level forms, as they don't relate at all.

Comment: There's also a section on cyclic expressions in Let Over Lambda: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html#sec_5

Comment: I think you got it by now, but the text you've quoted is enough to understand what's the label. In `#n=`, `n` is the label, an unsigned integer. The number after the hash (sharp-sign in CLHS) is typically an argument to dispatch macro characters. So, it's a number between `#` and `=` for labelling, `#` and `#` for referring. In a file that is loaded or compiled, every top-level expression is read separately, so each will be an outermost read. In a REPL, typically each prompt starts an outermost read.