# Circular list in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, circular-list

I am working using a visual programming environment for musical composition based on CL . I am trying to create a function that when given say 3 elements (1 2 3) will return 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc., one number at the time each time it is evaluated. The book *Common Lisp a Gentle Introduction*, mentions briefly that it's possible to create circular lists using sharp-equal notation but does not get into details on how to use them.
Keep in mind that I can insert actual Lisp code in the program using a object specifically designed for that.

Comment: Also see [Lisp cyclic lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15536564/1281433) and [Example of Sharpsign Equal-Sign reader macro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12649290/1281433).

Answer (score 19):

```
CL-USER 3 > (defun circular (items)
              (setf (cdr (last items)) items)
              items)
CIRCULAR

CL-USER 4 > (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER 5 > (circular (list 1 2 3))
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 16 > (setf c1 (circular (list 1 2 3)))
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)

CL-USER 17 > (pop c1)
1

CL-USER 18 > (pop c1)
2

CL-USER 19 > (pop c1)
3

CL-USER 20 > (pop c1)
1
```

also:

```
CL-USER 6 > '#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
#1=(1 2 3 . #1#)
```

With a bit of CLOS added:

```
(defclass circular ()
  ((items :initarg :items)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((c circular) &rest initargs)
  (setf (slot-value c 'items) (circular (slot-value c 'items))))

(defmethod next-item ((c circular))
  (prog1 (first (slot-value c 'items))
    (setf (slot-value c 'items)
          (rest (slot-value c 'items)))))

CL-USER 7 > (setf circ1 (make-instance 'circular :items (list 1 2 3)))
#<CIRCULAR 40200017CB>

CL-USER 8 > (next-item circ1)
1

CL-USER 9 > (next-item circ1)
2

CL-USER 10 > (next-item circ1)
3

CL-USER 11 > (next-item circ1)
1

CL-USER 12 > (next-item circ1)
2
```

Comment: Are there any books or sites you suggest that would help me learn more about this type of thing?

Comment: There's a section in Let Over Lambda on cyclic expressions: http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html#sec_5

Comment: There is no need to return `items` in the definition of `circular` as `setf` will return it anyway.

Comment: @tsikov: yes, but I wanted it to be clearer in the source and not to depend on the knowledge of the reader.

Answer (score 12):

In [Sharpsign Equal-Sign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dho.htm) notation, it's written as `#0=(1 2 3 . #0#)`.

Here's a function which creates such a list from the given arguments:

```
(defun circular (first &rest rest)
  (let ((items (cons first rest)))
    (setf (cdr (last items)) items)))
```

Then, calling `(circular 1 2 3)` will return the circular list you wanted. Just use `car` and `cdr` to iterate through the elements ad infinitum.

And if you really want an iterator function that takes no arguments and returns the next item for each call, here's how you might do it:

```
(defun make-iter (list)
  (lambda ()
    (pop list)))
```

Comment: You could use PROG1 instead of LET.

Comment: @ThomasBartscher Thanks! It's now implemented. (Actually I looked at Rainer's answer and it seems `pop` does the same thing as what I'm after. That's what happens when a Schemer tries to write CL. ;-))

Comment: Huh, I didn't think of that. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to let the printer know to recognize circular lists instead of trying to print the whole list:

```lisp
(setf *print-circle* t)
```

Next, you can create a circular list using the [Sharpsign Equal-Sign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dho.htm) notation:

```lisp
(setq x '#1=(1 2 3 . #1#))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea worked out for a circular list in Lisp.

```
;;; Showing structure of the list
;;; (next prev is-end val)

; create items
setf L-0 (L-1 L-3 t "L-0 sentry")  ; this will be the sentry item so know where to stop
setf L-1 (L-2 L-0 nil "L-1")
setf L-2 (L-3 L-1 nil "L-2")
setf L-3 (L-0 L-2 nil "L-3")

; how to access L-2 from L-0
eval (first (eval (first L-0)))

; result: (L-3 L-1 NIL "L-2")
```

I'm not giving defun functions to make adding, removing, and accessing the items. I'm thinking that what I gave is enough to show what you need to do in any functions you define for this kind of circular list. This appeared to me to work in the Listener.