# What does Python mean by printing "[...]" for an object reference?

Tags: python, recursion, ellipsis, recursive-datastructures

I'm printing a value of a what I thought was a list, but the output that I get is:

```
[...]
```

What does this represent? How do I test for it? I've tried:

```
myVar.__repr__() != '[...]'
```

and

```
myVar.__repr_() != Ellipsis
```

but no dice...

Here's a cutdown of the code that's giving the issue:

```
def buildPaths(graph, start, end, path=[], totalPaths=[]):
    """
    returns list of all possible paths from start node to the end node
    """
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    for nextNode in graph.childrenOf(start):
        if nextNode not in path:
            newPath = buildPaths(graph, nextNode, end, path, totalPaths)
            if newPath != []: # test
                totalPaths.append(newPath)
    return totalPaths
```

totalPaths contains a LOT of [...] supposedly recursive lists, but I can't see why. I've altered the test at #test to prevent this.

I've also tried:

```
def buildPaths(graph, thisNode, end, path=[], totalPaths=None):
    """
   returns list of all possible paths from start node to the end node
   """
    path = path + [thisNode]
    if thisNode == end:
        return path
    for nextNode in graph.childrenOf(thisNode):
        if nextNode not in path:
            newPath = buildPaths(graph, nextNode, end, path, totalPaths)
            if newPath != None:
                if totalPaths == None:
                    totalPaths = [newPath]
                else:
                    totalPaths.append(newPath)
    return totalPaths
```

in order to explicitly return `None` for empty paths.

Comment: Though `Ellipsis` is a thing in python, this is probably just whatever display telling you that there's more stuff to show than it can.  `>>> [...]` -> `[Ellipsis]` (since python3)

Comment: Can you provide an example of code that generates this?

Comment: @BrenBarn - example code added

Comment: When you do `totalPaths.append(newPath)`, that's modifying the passed-in list, so the parent recursion's `totalPaths` is also modified - then returned as `newPath` and appended to itself.

Comment: Thank you @Izkata - that was the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depending on the context here it could different things:

## indexing/slicing with `Ellipsis`

I think it's not implemented for any python class but it *should* represent an arbitary number of data structure nestings (*as much needed*). 
So for example: `a[..., 1]` should return all the second elements of the innermost nested structure:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)  # 3dimensional array
>>> a[..., 1]  # this returns a slice through the array in the third dimension
array([[ 1,  4,  7],
       [10, 13, 16],
       [19, 22, 25]])
>>> a[0, ...]  # This returns a slice through the first dimension
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

and to check for this `...` you compare it to an `Ellipsis` (this is a singleton so recommended is using `is`:

```
>>> ... is Ellipsis
True
>>> Ellipsis in [...]
True
# Another (more or less) equivalent alternative to the previous line:
>>> any(i is Ellipsis for i in [1, ..., 2]) 
True
```

## Recursive Datastructures

The other case in which you see an `[...]` in **your output** is if you have the sequence inside the sequence itself. Here it stands for an *infinite* deeply nested sequence (that's not printable). For example:

```
>>> alist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> alist[0] = alist
>>> alist
[[...], 'b', 'c']

# Infinite deeply nested so you can use as many leading [0] as you want
>>> alist[0][1] 
'b'
>>> alist[0][0][0][0][0][1] 
'b'
>>> alist[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][1] 
'b'
```

You can even replace it several times:

```
>>> alist[2] = alist
>>> alist
[[...], 'b', [...]]
>>> alist[1] = alist
>>> alist
[[...], [...], [...]]
```

To test if you have any such recursion in your output you need to check if the data-structure itself is also one of the elements:

```
>>> alist in alist
True
>>> any(i is alist for i in alist)
True
```

Another way to get a more meaningful output is using `pprint.pprint`:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(alist)  # Assuming you only replaced the first element:
[<Recursion on list with id=1628861250120>, 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 49):

It represents an infinite loop within the structure.  An example:

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2]

In [2]: l[0] = l

In [3]: l
Out[3]: [[...], 2]
```

`l`'s first item is itself.  It's a recursive reference, and so python can't reasonably display its contents.  Instead it shows `[...]`

Comment: Well, it could show the results if it's being lazily computed. GHCi has no problem displaying an infinite list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Practically speaking, GHCi has no problem starting to display an infinite list, but it has difficulty finishing... Python sort of requires repr to finish executing before printing.

Comment: Common Lisp has a special notation for printing "circular" list structure, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678371/circular-list-in-common-lisp

Answer (score 21):

If your list contains self references Python will display that as `[...]` rather than trying to recursively print it out, which would lead to an infinte loop:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l.append(l)
>>> print(l)
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> print(l[-1])        # print the last item of list l
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> print(l[-1][-1])    # print the last item of the last item of list l
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

ad infinitum.

A similar situation arises with dictionaries:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['key'] = d
>>> print(d)
{'key': {...}}
>>> d['key']
{'key': {...}}
>>> d['key']['key']
{'key': {...}}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's a recursive reference as your list contains itself. Python doesn't try to recursively print this which would lead to an infinite loop.

`repr` detects this. So, if you looked at the internal representation of your list object you would see (where the ellipsis occur) "Reference to the same list object at address *" where * is the address of the original list object in memory. Hence, the infinite loop.